# select from multiple columns but retrieve column name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

```
tbl.device
ID  SERIAL CD   
--------------
1   123    51974
2   222    8733
3   888    321233

tbl.space
ID  SPACE1  SPACE2  SPACE3
------------------------------
1   -1      -1      555
2   -1      888     -611
3   222     -1      -1
```

Now I would like to get result from tbl.device with this (with the name of SPACE a.k.a column name, but if device is not in space, then ommit device):

```
id  serial  cd      spaceitisin
2   222     8733    SPACE1  
3   888     321233  SPACE2
```

What is the best select query for this? (I think I will need to use IF THEN in mysql query to get column name but I am not familiar with it how).

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below using `UNION` and `JOIN`

```
select b.id,serial,cd, spaceitisin from
(
select space1 as spaceid,'space1' spaceitisin from tbl.space
union 
select space2,'space2' spaceitisin from tbl.space
union 
select space3,'space3' spaceitisin from tbl.space
)a inner join tbl.device b on a.spaceid=b.serial
```

Comment: both queries work (@Mureinik and @fa06) - thank you! So I do not know which to mark as correct answer :) Probably - which one query will be faster? @Mureinik's or 
@fa06's?

Comment: ok, so I made some tests on larger table and in my case UNION has much better performance than CASE.

Answer (score 2):

You could `join` the tables and use a `case` expression to see what column you joined on:

```
SELECT d.*,
       CASE d.serial 
            WHEN s.space1 THEN 'space1'
            WHEN s.space2 THEN 'space2'
            WHEN s.space3 THEN 'space3'
       END
FROM   device d
JOIN   space s ON d.serial IN (s.space1, s.space2, s.space3)
```

Comment: both queries work (@Mureinik and @fa06) - thank you! So I do not know which to mark as correct answer :) Probably - which one query will be faster? @Mureinik's or 
@fa06's?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
select d.*,
       field(d.serial, s.space1, s.space2, s.space3) as which
from device d join
     space s
     on d.serial in (s.space1, s.space2, s.space3);
```

This returns the column as a "number" -- I suspect that is what you want.

If you want an arbitrary string. you can use `elt()`:

```
select d.*,
       elt(field(d.serial, s.space1, s.space2, s.space3), 'SPACE1', 'SPACE2', 'SPACE3') as which
from device d join
     space s
     on d.serial in (s.space1, s.space2, s.space3);
```